# How to interact with websocket from within R

Tags: r, websocket, client

I'm on R 3.1.2 and want to interact with a websocket over a private ip within R. In the past, I've tried using [websockets](https://github.com/rstudio/R-Websockets) package and had memory/cpu usage problems and crashes with it, admittedly after several hours.

From the documentation, I see that it is now deprecated and [httpuv](https://github.com/rstudio/httpuv) package is recommended.

Am I reading correctly that httpuv is a websockets server and not a R client.

Are there any other packages I can use to interact with the websocket from inside R.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similar question a while back and it was confirmed to me by Joe Cheng (maintainer of httpuv) that httpuv is a websocket server only. That still seems to be true with httpuv 1.3.2 dated 2014-10-22.

Comment: Hello @Yoda, Martin Studer, just wondering if you ultimately have found an R package to "consume" websocket, i.e.: a websocket client library for R, please? Thx.

Comment: Well, there is https://github.com/rstudio/R-Websockets which unfortunately is no longer maintained.

Comment: Indeed no joy. I've used the websockets package with Sys.sleep(1) in the while loop. That helps to mitigate the crashes. Rather sad that the only websockets client package for R is deprecated. Installing websockets is a little more work since there it is not on CRAN anymore.

Comment: Any update on this?